# Get classloader using typetag in scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, types, classloader

Is it possible in scala to get the classloader of a class using its typetag?

Using `getClass().getClassLoader` in the class that uses the typetag gets the classloader of the current class which may not be the same as the classloader for the type in the tag.

I want to create instances of a type whose only information I have is the typetag.  I want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirrors have an associated classloader:

```
scala> typeTag[Foo[Bar]].mirror.classLoader
res6: ClassLoader = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@34b89ddd
```

Comment: What happens if Foo and Bar were loaded by different classloaders?

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh if you ask a universe about a type it doesn't know about, it will tell you severely.